# Mapping a texture in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, texture-mapping, freeglut

I am trying to map a texture to a simple quad for the first time, but all it won't render. I am using freeglut for the implementation, and the stb_image.h header to load the texture.
The code:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>   
#include <stb_image.h>
#include <iostream>
int ww = 500, wh = 500;

void display()
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 0.7, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(10,10,0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(10,wh-10,0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(ww-10,wh,0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(ww-10,10,0);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}


void myinit()
{   
    glViewport(0, 0, ww, wh);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, (GLdouble)ww, 0.0, (GLdouble)wh);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    unsigned int texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    int width, height, nrChannels;
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load("container.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(ww, wh);
    glutCreateWindow("texture-try");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    myinit();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

It successfully loads the texture, but the quad appears just white.
What am I missing?

**Edit:**

I moved the `glBegin(GL_QUADS);` and `glEnd();` inside the `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` and `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` commands as was suggested, but it still won't render the texture.

I also checked the `glGetError` command, but it returns `GL_NO_ERROR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

- The aforementioned "don't use prohibited functions within a `glBegin()`/`glEnd()` pair" issue; as of posting this hasn't been fixed in the question code.
- `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR` is being used without providing any mipmaps.  Drop to `GL_LINEAR` or provide some mipmaps.
- Pass `3` to `stbi_load()`'s `desired_channels` parameter (instead of the current `0`) to guarantee you get 3-channel image data instead of just assuming `nrChannels` is `3` for all input images.
- Using `GL_RGB` with the default `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` of `4` can result in wonky display if your image width isn't a nice multiple of 4 so drop that down to `1` via `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)` before calling `glTexImage2D()`.
- Switch to `GLUT_DOUBLE` & `glutSwapBuffers()` instead of using `GLUT_SINGLE` and `glFlush()`.

All together:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>   
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb_image.h>
#include <iostream>
int ww = 500, wh = 500;

void display()
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 0.7, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(10,10,0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(10,wh-10,0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(ww-10,wh,0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(ww-10,10,0);
    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}


void myinit()
{   
    glViewport(0, 0, ww, wh);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, (GLdouble)ww, 0.0, (GLdouble)wh);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    unsigned int texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    int width, height, nrChannels;
    // https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Container.JPG
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load("container.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 3);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    if (data)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(ww, wh);
    glutCreateWindow("texture-try");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    myinit();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

From the OpenGL documentation for glBegin:

> Only a subset of GL commands can be used between glBegin and glEnd. The commands are glVertex, glColor, glSecondaryColor, glIndex, glNormal, glFogCoord, glTexCoord, glMultiTexCoord, glVertexAttrib, glEvalCoord, glEvalPoint, glArrayElement, glMaterial, and glEdgeFlag. Also, it is acceptable to use glCallList or glCallLists to execute display lists that include only the preceding commands. If any other GL command is executed between glBegin and glEnd, the error flag is set and the command is ignored.

In other words, you can't enable/disable texturing within a glBegin/glEnd block.

```cpp
void display()
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 0.7, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    
    // move to before glBegin
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(10,10,0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(10,wh-10,0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(ww-10,wh,0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(ww-10,10,0);
    glEnd();

    // move to after glEnd
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glFlush();
}
```

Comment: I moved it, but it still won't render